# Optimal placement of radio towers

Tags: optimization

Imagine there is an area on which you have to put radio towers. Each radio tower sends signal to a circular area of fixed size.

How do I determine the optimal number and placements of these towers so the overlapping areas are as small as possible, the whole area is in range of towers, and the number of towers is minimal?

Comment: 1) You optimize several things (number of towers and overlapping area), so it's impossible to answer unless you specify what you want to optimize first 2) If we only minimize the number of towers, I believe it can be done in polynomial time: ["Efficient Algorithms for Geometric Optimization"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/299917.299918) (section 7.1)

Comment: First I would like to make sure the overlapping area is as small as possible while whole area to be covered is actually covered. So that would be point of optimization, I believe that the tower count would be minimal still.